# Databricks : Export data profiling report

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, data-profiling

Databricks can create a data profiling report after using the `display(dataframe_name)`.
I have created a data profiling report using Azure Databricks but I do not know how do I export it.
Can you please suggest How to export/download this report to my local system?

Comment: Do you want to be able to use the data profile's information somewhere else?

Comment: I want to create a report whatever is available in dataprofile. As I have multiple dataframes so will collate all the information.

Comment: There is no option provided to download this data profile to local machine directly, only option is to add it to dashboard. You can export the notebook as HTML file if required

Comment: but I want to download the report in tabular format only :(

Comment: As far as I know, there might not be an option present to download the report in tabular format. These data profiles might be created as a tool to visualize/analyze data within the databricks workspace.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help and the efforts. I really appreciate it 

Comment: Will post it as an answer so it might help other community members. Would update the answer if I find any other alternative to download data profile in tabular format, I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- There is no direct option to download the data profiling report from Azure Databricks to local machine in a tabular format.
- Data profiling itself is a new feature that was introduced to reduce manual work that is needed to summarize the statistics of our dataframes.
- And as specified in this [official Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/notebooks/visualizations/#display-function), we can only add the data profile to our dashboard.
- There are also no other API's that can be used to download this data in tabular format.
- As a possible workaround, it might be possible to complete this operation manually using pandas/ pandas on spark API to calculate all the required attributes.
- In general, some of these stats can be directly obtained using `df.describe` as shown below. Here `df` is a pyspark dataframe:

[image]